# Appdelegate print() not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to open my iOS app from and URL but when I put NSURL into fund application print() doesn't working.

please refer here

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
    var openUrl:NSURL? //This is used when to save state when App is not running before the url trigered


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  //print("Host: \(url.host!)")
    //let url = url.standardized
    //NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "HANDLEOPENURL"), object:url!)
    print("bbb")
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you use `Foundation` instead of swift?

Comment: What do you mean _"application print() doesn't working."_? What do you expect to see? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: An addition to what @AshleyMills commented: do you receive any warning/issue? I cannot reproduce this error

Comment: nothing appears on debug screen on emulator but when I delete the line  openURL url: NSURL, I can see bbb in screen ?? why??

Comment: I expect to see bbb but I cannot, when delete openURL url: NSURL, bbb appears on screen

Comment: its very easy question I am new to iOS why nobody can answer interesting?

Answer (score 1):

There is no AppDelegate method with that signature, so its not getting called

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

The correct method signature is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`
```

You are confusing it with this method

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

**EDIT**
To respond to links from the web to iOS, use

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
```

Comment: its even not printing with this ==  func application(_ application: UIApplication){
        print("bbb")
       
    }

Comment: @tumaz I think you need to review the basics of iOS app development and Swift.  You can't just expect arbitrary methods in AppDelegate to get called.  They need to conform to what Apple has documented in its frameworks

Comment: i am just trying like on the android

Comment: func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
     
        print("bbb")

    } this is calling

Comment: Please review the documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

Comment: No wonder my initializer code in the old method was not being called and crashed my app. Do I look like a clairvoyant Apple? or a seer?